# Switch in elegant way in java 1.6 for string

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm using java 1.6 and i know that from java 1.7 there is option to switch on string 
but here i use the if/elseif to route type name,my question if there is a elegant way 
that i can change it to switch Yet

```
public static SwitchType<?> switchT(final String typeName,
                                    final String memberName) {

    if (typeName.equals("java.lang.String")) {
        return new SwitchInputType<String>(new String(memberName + " "));

    } else if (typeName.equals("char")) {
        return new SwitchInputType<Character>(new Character('a'));

    } else if (typeName.equals("decimal") || 
               typeName.equals("java.math.BigDecimal")) {
        return new SwitchInputType<BigDecimal>(new BigDecimal("34.58"));

    } else if (typeName.equals("boolean")) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Map<String, SwitchTypeFactory>`:

```
public interface SwitchTypeFactory {
   SwitchType<?> create(String memberName);
}

...

private static Map<String, SwitchTypeFactory> factories = new HashMap<String, SwitchTypeFactory>();

static {
   factories.put("java.lang.String", new SwitchTypeFactory() {
        @Override
        public SwitchType<?> create(String memberName) {
            return new SwitchInputType<String>(memberName + " ");
        }
    });

    factories.put("char", new SwitchTypeFactory() {
        @Override
        public SwitchType<?> create(String memberName) {
            return new SwitchInputType<Character>(Character.valueOf('a'))
        }
    });
    ...
}

public static SwitchType<?> switchT(final String typeName, final String memberName) {
    return factories.get(typeName).create(memberName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the static should be in new class ?

Comment: and what does it mean that you write just static

Comment: @JeanTennie 1) No. 2) The "static { ... }" is a *static initializer*.  Look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Many patterns are available, from the use of an enumeration to the use of a `Map<String,Implementation>` but none of them will be more concise nor faster that what you have in this precise case. They would only make sense if more code was dependent of this `typeName`.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @JeanTennie JB Nizet just did it.

Answer (score 1):

Although it might be a little counter intuitive using `enum` has proven quite powerful in that regard.

Every `enum` has a `valueOf(String)` method that returns an Element for that name. Then you may use the retrieved Element in a switch statement. The only ugly part is that `valueOf(String)` throws an `IllegalArgumentException`. So catching that is equivalent to a default case.

```
enum Type{
    JAVA_LANG_STRING;
    CHAR;
    DECIMAL;
    BOOLEAN;
    JAVA_LANG_BIGDECIMAL;
}

public static SwitchType<?> switchT(final String typeName,
                                final String memberName) {

    try{
    Type t = Type.valueOf(typeName.toUppercase().replace(".","_"));
    switch(t){
    case Type.JAVA_LANG_STRING: return new SwitchInputType<String>(new String(memberName + " "));
    case Type.CHAR: return new SwitchInputType<Character>(new Character('a'));
    case Type.DECIMAL:
    case Type.JAVA_MATH_BIGDECIMAL: return new SwitchInputType<BigDecimal>(new BigDecimal("34.58"));
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        //default case
    }
}
```

Also enums may implement interfaces. Either by providing one implementation for each element or one global one.

```
interface SwitchInputTypeFacotry {

    SwitchInputType get(String arg);

}
enum TypeName implements SwitchInputTypeFacotry{
    CHAR{
        SwitchInputType get(String arg){
            return new SwitchInputType<Character>(new Character('a'));
        }
    }
    [...]
}

public static SwitchType<?> switchT(final String typeName,
                                final String memberName) {

    try{
        SwitchInputTypeFacotry t = Type.valueOf(typeName.toUppercase().replace(".","_"));
        return t.get(memberName);
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        //default case
    }
}
```

The second way makes it very easy to extend functionality (as long as it stays in one module, subclassing is not possible with enums).